# Right tools for parsing XSD to XML and vice versa

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, jaxb, sax

I have joined as an intern at I'm assigned a work to convert `XSD` files into a given `XML` format and then make an `HTML` form from it . I've been researching a lot I have come up with a lot of ways in which it can be done:

- Parsing -> SAX , StAX , DOM
- Marshalling and Unmarshalling using JAXB
- JAXP
- XSOM
- dom4j
- JAXF

Now, I'm completely confused as to which one to use. So, far I've used SAX and DOM for parsing. If somebody could help me figure out the *right tools* and if I have missed out any.

Comment: you can't convert a XSD to XML, that's non sense. Do you want to generate a Sample XML that respect an XSD ?

Comment: Yes, what I meant was I'm trying to generate a XML with respect to the given XML schema.